# Gradle failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0

Tags: android, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, google-signin

I am trying to use google log in in my mobile app but I am getting following error after following google's tutorial.

> "failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0"

My gradle files :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the other one is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
}
```

So what is wrong here and why I cannot build the project?

Comment: refer to the setup guide : note the comments in block capitals regarding the placement for the plugin  and the maven repository: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same issue and I was able to resolve it by adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to list of repositories in project level build.gradle as shown below.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Also, ensure this `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` comes after your dependencies to avoid version issues.

Answer (score 2):

**Identifying the issue:**

There is a conflict in libraries version, you are using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'` and that's the last version **now** which required a compatible `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

**Why it's happened?:**

Compiling `lib` contain a higher `api` level than your *app* `api` level make that.

**Solution:**

Upload your `compileSdkVersion` also `targetSdkVersion` to last version **(Now it's `27`)** , and your `com.android.support` too, to be compatible with whole *app* and libs.

Also you have to add `google()` to your repositories as well:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
.........
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter() 
    google()
    }
}
```

Note: Updating `targetSdkVersion` not required for this issue, but it's better to product *app* targeting a wide range of devices.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to update your `targetSdkVersion` at the same time as your `compileSdkVersion` as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

Comment: this time it cannot find google(). I am getting this error : "Error:(6, 0) Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container."

Comment: @user1474111 it's seems you're using AS version 2.3.3 therefor you have to use `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`  instead of `google()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have downloaded GooglePlay Services in SDK Manager

Please, move this line  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the end of the gradle file (it MUST be at the end)

Also, you may upgrade versions :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

Add also `google()` in repositories :

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'}
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter() 
            google()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: need to also add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` repo as well as its not included in OP's manifest.

Comment: @MarkKeen Indeed `google()` replace that.